# NodeJS 12.x https version of a curl request on AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, curl, https, aws-lambda

```
    curl -d "m_payment_id=m_payment_id-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxyyy&pf_payment_id=990396&payment_status=COMPLETE&item_name=Subscription&item_description=Monthly+Subscription&amount_gross=99.00&amount_fee=-6.74&amount_net=92.26&custom_str1=&custom_str2=&custom_str3=&custom_str4=&custom_str5=&custom_int1=&custom_int2=&custom_int3=&custom_int4=&custom_int5=&name_first=&name_last=&email_address=christo%40g4-ape.co.za&merchant_id=0000000&token=0000000-0000-0000-3a83-25bc733a307b&billing_date=2020-02-21&signature=3895d0769b56862b842da5067af4483f" -X POST https://sandbox.somedomain.co.za/what/something/validate
```

My attempt:

```
const https = require("https");
const querystring = "m_payment_id=m_payment_id-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxyyy&pf_payment_id=990396&payment_status=COMPLETE&item_name=Subscription&item_description=Monthly+Subscription&amount_gross=99.00&amount_fee=-6.74&amount_net=92.26&custom_str1=&custom_str2=&custom_str3=&custom_str4=&custom_str5=&custom_int1=&custom_int2=&custom_int3=&custom_int4=&custom_int5=&name_first=&name_last=&email_address=christo%40g4-ape.co.za&merchant_id=0000000&token=0000000-0000-0000-3a83-25bc733a307b&billing_date=2020-02-21&signature=3895d0769b56862b842da5067af4483f";

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const options = {
            hostname: 'sandbox.somedomain.co.za',
            port: 443,
            path: 'what/something/validate',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(querystring)
            }
        };

        const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
            console.log('statusCode: ' + res.statusCode);
            console.log('headers: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
            res.setEncoding('utf8');

            let data = '';
            res.on('data', (chunk) => {
                data += chunk;
            });
            res.on('end', () => {
                console.log('BODY: ' + data);
            });

            resolve('Success');
        });

        req.on('error', (e) => {
            console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
            reject(e.message);
        });

        // write data to request body
        req.write(querystring);
        req.end();
    });
```

I keep getting a statusCode 400 on the NodeJS code, the curl works fine. The hostname hs obviously been changed for security.

Can someone please advise me on what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Content-Length is reqired when you are sending the body while posting. In your case all the info is getting passed as query string parameter so you can get rid of the headers alltogather.

Also, you should be resolving inside `res.on('end'`. THe way you are doing it will finish the function before it even finishes execution.

Comment: I removed the headers altogether and also moved the resolve('Success')
`res.on('end', () => {
                    console.log('BODY: ' + data);
                    resolve('Success');
                });`

But it still doesn't work.